# Pygame hitboxes blinking

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to make a game using pygame, I am almost done but I want to make the boxes that are being drawn in-wall object to not blink, these red boxes blink throughout the game which I don't want them to and further, In the end, I am calling playercollide function in an if condition, here whenever I make new collider I have to add the function in if condition every time, what I want is that collider object automatically calls this function, without me calling it in if statement for every instance of collider object. Please guide me on how to do so.

```
def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg, (-50,-200))
    man.draw(win)
    #man.drawhitbox(win)
    pygame.display.update()


#mainloop

man = player(200, 410, 64,64)
run = True
while run:
    collider1 = wall(500, 400, 200, 200, True)
    collider2 = wall(200,100,50, 50, False)
    collider3 = wall(700,100,50, 50, False)
    collider4 = wall(900,100,50,50, True)
    clock.tick(60)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    x, y = man.x, man.y

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and man.x > man.vel:
        x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and man.x < scrWidth - man.width - man.vel:
        x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_w] and man.y > man.vel:
        y -= man.vel
        man.left = False
        man.right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_s] and man.y < scrHeight - man.height - man.vel:
        y+= man.vel
        man.left = False
        man.right = False
    else:
        man.right = False
        man.left = False
        man.walkCount = 0

    man.hitbox(15, 0, 31, 17)
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 50, 55)
    if collider2.playerCollide(player_rect) == False and collider1.playerCollide(player_rect) == False and collider3.playerCollide(player_rect) == False and collider4.playerCollide(player_rect) == False:
        man.x, man.y = x, y
    redrawGameWindow()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is cause by the multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()`. Remove the call to `pygame.display.update()` from the class `wall` and do just 1 `pygame.display.update()` at the end of `redrawGameWindow`.
However, you must draw the background before you draw the boxes, otherwise the background will cover the boxes:

```py
def redrawGameWindow():
    # win.blit(bg, (-50,-200)) <--- DELETE
    man.draw(win)
    #man.drawhitbox(win)
    pygame.display.update()
```

```py
run = True
while run:
    win.blit(bg, (-50,-200)) # <--- ADD

    collider1 = wall(500, 400, 200, 200, True)
    collider2 = wall(200,100,50, 50, False)
    collider3 = wall(700,100,50, 50, False)
    collider4 = wall(900,100,50,50, True)

    # [...]

    redrawGameWindow()
```

---

Simplify the code by creating a list of colliders:

```py
colliders = [
   wall(500, 400, 200, 200, True),
   wall(200,100,50, 50, False),
   wall(700,100,50, 50, False),
   wall(900,100,50,50, True)]
```

```py
player_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 50, 55)
if not any(c.playerCollide(player_rect) for c in colliders):
    man.x, man.y = x, y
```

Comment: this does not print collider boxes then.
that's why I have to call it there

Comment: That worked thanks.
and can you please tell how do I make the last if condition call itself automatically for each instance without me adding playercollide for all instances

Comment: @007AZx See the answer.